# How to handle Google OAuth flow via redux-saga

Tags: react-redux, google-oauth, redux-saga

I am trying to implement Google OAuth 2 with with redux saga.

I have a watcher in my saga listening for `GOOGLE_AUTH` action which then executes `googleLogin`

```
function *watchGoogleAuth() {
   yield *takeLatest(GOOGLE_AUTH, googleLogin)
}

function *googleLogin() {
  const id_token = yield call(GoogleSignIn);
  console.log(id_token);
  const response = yield call(HttpHelper, 'google_token', 'POST', id_token, null);
  console.log(response);
}
```

The implementation for `GoogleSignIn` is in `apis.js`

```
export function GoogleSignIn() {
  const GoogleAuth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

    GoogleAuth.signIn({scope: 'profile email'})
      .then(
        (res) => {
          const GoogleUser = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
          return {
            id_token: GoogleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token
          };
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err)
        }
      )
}
```

But saga doesn't seem to wait for the `GoogleSignIn` to complete. As soon as OAuth consent screen pops up, saga proceeds executing the `console.log` without waiting for google signin promise to return actual data.

Is there any better way to handle this situation? Thanks!

Comment: GoogleSignIn function should return promise

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @HenrikR's answer, the generator will not wait unless it receives a promise.

```
export const GoogleSignIn = () => {
  const GoogleAuth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    GoogleAuth.signIn({scope: 'profile email'})
      .then(
        (res) => {
          const GoogleUser = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
          resolve(GoogleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
        },
        (err) => {
          reject(err);
        }
      );
  });
};
```

Accordingly, you should wrap the yield statement in a try/catch. Simplified and somewhat lazy:

```
function *googleLogin() {
  try {
    const id_token = yield call(GoogleSignIn);
    if (id_token) { /* Possibly with more checks and validations */
      console.log(id_token);
      const response = yield call(HttpHelper, 'google_token', 'POST', id_token, null);
      console.log(response);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```